# Derivation of Michaelis' Equation from Michaelis' Constants

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, enzymes

The enzyme reaction condition, $E + S \leftrightarrow ES \rightarrow E + P$ uses $\kappa_{1}$ (forward reaction), $\kappa_{-1}$ and $\kappa_{2}$ as the rate constants.

E: Enzyme
S: Substrate
P: Product

What is the relationship between $\kappa_{1}$, $\kappa_{-1}$ and $\kappa_{2}$ to yield Michaelis's constant:

$\kappa_{m}$ = ($\kappa_{-1}$ + $\kappa_{2}$) / $\kappa_{2}$ ?

I understand that $\kappa_{m}$ = $S$ at $1/2 \times V_{max}$, however I do not understand the relationship of the rate constants based on the enzyme reaction condition.

This question has been marked as a repeat of the question "How does pH affect Michaelis' constant". I am not asking for any affect with pH, just a proof for the mathematical relationship of the factors shown above.

Comment: I edited this question to ask for a proof, rather than a relationship with pH.

Comment: If you're asking for a derivation of the Michaelis-Menten law, I think that is actually a good question, because many biochemistry books are not very clear on this, even though the law itself is common knowledge. The best derivation I have found is the one given in Atkins' Physical Chemistry, http://www.amazon.com/Physical-Chemistry-Edition-Peter-Atkins/dp/1429218126

Comment: I've made some formulaic layout edits, if they are incorrect could you change them @rocc also could you say what all the letters *mean* (e.g. ´´where $E$ is for Elephants´´)

Comment: They are correct, thank you. I will put in the variable names.

Comment: @Roland, yes I am asking for a derivation of the law, but preferably in standard proof format. I will look at the link you posted.

Comment: I realized the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics  does a pretty good job with the derivation actually. Also, please note that the Michaelis-Menten reaction rate formula is often used phenomenologically without really considering the model, just to have some rough description of saturation w.r.t. the substrate.